Why can I not read a body stream multiple times in javascript?
If I do something like:
    fetch(...)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.text(), res.text())
    })

I'll get: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read
Why does the readablestream get locked? I don't get the reasoning behind disallowing this

you may be able to - using the response.clone() method

That's the entire idea of a stream. You consume it and retain only the information that you need.
The stream API gives you access to the data as it becomes available, and avoids having to keep everything in memory.

As to why the choice was made to implement the response body as a stream, I came across the following reasoning from T.J. Crowder:


In theory, the browser can avoid loading the entire body into memory and then doing something with it (parsing as JSON, loading into
an ArrayBuffer, etc.); instead, depending on the method you call,
the browser can feed the response's network stream directly to the
JSON parser, or ArrayBuffer builder, or Blob builder, etc.

The parsing/etc. can happen in concert with the read (in theory that would mean an early error in the JSON would allow it to avoid
continuing to read the body).

The Response object doesn't have to keep a copy of the body after you've consumed it in case you call json() or such again;
keeping the result is the job of the code using the response.




But then one could ask why is res a stream here? Before we had access to the body  property, all its methods were just the ones we have on Blob, so the API could have been to actually return a Blob.

@Kaiido I assume it's about efficiency. See also T.J. Crowder's reasoning here.

I think it's more that the fetch API (of which fetch() is part) is not only intended for web-authors, but for everything in the browser that does fetch resources. So it was clear from the get-go that a stream version was needed (even if a that time the Web Stream API wasn't entirely finalized), because some of these consumers were already expecting a stream, where indeed it makes sense to have the body consumable only once. The Response class accessible to JS consumers is only a wrapper over the actual response  that all consumers receive, so it makes sense it acts the same.

For instance T.J.'s reasoning about .json() is off, because the specs actually ask that the full ArrayBuffer ("byte sequence") is loaded before the UA tries to read it as UTF-8 and then parse it as JSON. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-json -> https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body -> https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-fully-read -> https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#readablestreamdefaultreader-read-all-bytes so the "optimization" they were envisioning would actually be against the specs.

@Kaiido True for the standard .json() call, but nothing prevents you from using a streaming JSON parser like this one to consume the stream.

Yes, that's my point exactly. The JS API could actually have been that the Response object we get is only a Blob or the body ReadableStream. So while the Stream API was being incubated, there was no need to make .json() consume the body every time. So, before we get the ReadableStream, the only motivation was more likely that later on we'd expose the streaming capabilities to JS too rather than any "optimization".
